# Lync API: How to send instant message to contact by email address?

Tags: c#, lync, lync-2010

I have the email address of a Lync user and want to send him an instant message.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation;


namespace Build_Server_Lync_Notifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: bsln.exe <uri> <message>");
                return;
            }

            LyncClient client = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient();
            Contact contact = client.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(args[0]);

            Conversation conversation = client.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
            conversation.AddParticipant(contact);

            Dictionary<InstantMessageContentType, String> messages = new Dictionary<InstantMessageContentType, String>();
            messages.Add(InstantMessageContentType.PlainText, args[1]);

            InstantMessageModality m = (InstantMessageModality) conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.InstantMessage];
            m.BeginSendMessage(messages, null, messages);

            //Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

**Screenshot**
[image: Lync problems]
Link to large screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTHej.png

As you can see in this screenshot, my program doesn't really seem to work, even though I'm able to manually search up the contact and send an instant message manually.

I also tried using `ContactManager.BeginSearch()` instead of `ContactManager.GetContactByUri()`, but got the same result (you can see in the screenshot): http://pastie.org/private/o9joyzvux4mkhzsjw1pioa

Comment: I can't see anything to state why it is not working, can you enable debug logs in lync (settings under general "tab") and put the output here

Comment: @Neo http://pastie.org/private/igdb3rgsdjfmujyl2j7q

Comment: I will try to compare the log from a successful (manual) attempt with the log from my C# failed attempt in the mean time.

Comment: Well there are some errors there that mean nothing to me but look a little suspicious as for why the message isn't sending, it is saying it can't match the SIP data or the host (09/26/2012|20:26:20.335 16E8:1488 ERROR :: SIP_URL::InternalInitialize Didn't find host while parsing SIP URL)  I'd look into this one first as this should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, so I got it working now. Got it in a working state, although I need to do some serious refactoring.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;

namespace Build_Server_Lync_Notifier
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length != 2)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Usage: bsln.exe <uri> <message>");
                return;
            }

            LyncManager lm = new LyncManager(args[0], args[1]);

            while (!lm.Done) 
            {
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**LyncManager.cs**

```
using Microsoft.Lync.Model;
using Microsoft.Lync.Model.Conversation;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Build_Server_Lync_Notifier
{
    class LyncManager
    {
        private string _uri;
        private string _message;
        private LyncClient _client;
        private Conversation _conversation;

        private bool _done = false;
        public bool Done
        {
            get { return _done; }
        }

        public LyncManager(string arg0, string arg1)
        {
            _uri = arg0;
            _message = arg1;
            _client = Microsoft.Lync.Model.LyncClient.GetClient();
            _client.ContactManager.BeginSearch(
                _uri,
                SearchProviders.GlobalAddressList,
                SearchFields.EmailAddresses,
                SearchOptions.ContactsOnly,
                2,
                BeginSearchCallback,
                new object[] { _client.ContactManager, _uri }
            );
        }

        private void BeginSearchCallback(IAsyncResult r)
        {
            object[] asyncState = (object[]) r.AsyncState;
            ContactManager cm = (ContactManager) asyncState[0];
            try
            {
                SearchResults results = cm.EndSearch(r);
                if (results.AllResults.Count == 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No results.");
                }
                else if (results.AllResults.Count == 1)
                {
                    ContactSubscription srs = cm.CreateSubscription();
                    Contact contact = results.Contacts[0];
                    srs.AddContact(contact);
                    ContactInformationType[] contactInformationTypes = { ContactInformationType.Availability, ContactInformationType.ActivityId };
                    srs.Subscribe(ContactSubscriptionRefreshRate.High, contactInformationTypes);
                    _conversation = _client.ConversationManager.AddConversation();
                    _conversation.AddParticipant(contact);
                    Dictionary<InstantMessageContentType, String> messages = new Dictionary<InstantMessageContentType, String>();
                    messages.Add(InstantMessageContentType.PlainText, _message);
                    InstantMessageModality m = (InstantMessageModality)_conversation.Modalities[ModalityTypes.InstantMessage];
                    m.BeginSendMessage(messages, BeginSendMessageCallback, messages);
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("More than one result.");
                }
            }
            catch (SearchException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Search failed: " + se.Reason.ToString());
            }
            _client.ContactManager.EndSearch(r);
        }

        private void BeginSendMessageCallback(IAsyncResult r)
        {
            _conversation.End();
            _done = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try Below Code its working Fine For me

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   SendLyncMessage();
}
private static void SendLyncMessage()
{
  string[] targetContactUris = {"sip:xxxx@domain.com"};
  LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
  Conversation conv = client.ConversationManager.AddConversation();

  foreach (string target in targetContactUris)
  {
     conv.AddParticipant(client.ContactManager.GetContactByUri(target));
  }
  InstantMessageModality m = conv.Modalities[ModalityTypes.InstantMessage] as InstantMessageModality;
  m.BeginSendMessage("Test Message", null, null);
}
```